# Run OpenCV script on start with imshow

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have an OpenCV/python script running at my Raspberry Pi which reads the camera and shows the stream on the RCA monitor connected to the Pi.

Now I want the script to be loaded on boot. I already tried a cronjob @reboot, the /etc/rc.locale, /etc/profile and ~/.bash_profile.

I see the red light of the camera turning on every time, but the image won't be shown. Is there any solution to run the script? (I have no external input devices connected)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know its quite an old thread, but I thought you might be still interested in a solution that worked for me. Hopefully, that can help you as well:

[Raspberry Pi - Autostart OpenCv-Script - Error with cv::imshow()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411763/raspberry-pi-autostart-opencv-script-error-with-cvimshow/47413583#47413583)

In short: You most likely have problems with the DISPLAY / XAUTHORITY environment variable.